# SharePoint UserProfile ChoiceList - comma is an invalid charcter for the picker control?

Tags: sharepoint, user-profile

We are storing an office address field on a user profile in our MOSS installation. For the field I'd like to use a choice list to limit the user to selecting an office with the address in the correct format.

The office address is the full address of the office (rather than just an id of some kind as one might use) - this is so that the value can be indexed and the search interface can then find everyone based in London (for example) or 'UK Office' as these are part of the address. All good so far, an example office address might be:

```
999 Letsbe Avenue, South Kensington, London SW1 1AA
```

I can add this value to the choice list successfully and looking at the UserProfile.ChoiceList proprty shows it correctly. Looking at it in the Edit Profile page is fine, the picker control shows the value correctly too. Only problem is, if you try and select it in the picker control - let's say double click on it - the value isn't passed to the text control on the page - instead the picker refreshes and shows no values.

Playing with the values shows that it's the commas in the value that cause the problem with the picker, so has anyone experienced this and fixed it / worked around it with anything other than just not using commas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's one I just checked works - Unicode Character 'SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK' (U+201A).

just have to be careful with the font used on the site in case it's rendered oddly, but it'll workaround it unless there is a 'proper' solution.